# run ssh command remotely without redirecting output

Tags: python, ssh, openssh

I want to run a python script on my server (that python script has GUI). But I want to start it from ssh. Something like this:

- `ssh me@server -i my_key "nohup python script.py"`
  ... > let the script run forever
  BUT it complains "unable to access video driver" since it is trying to use my ssh terminal as output.

Can I somehow make my commands output run on server machine and not to my terminal... Basically something like "wake-on-lan functionality" -> tell the server you want something and he will do everything using its own system (not sending any output back)

Comment: If you don't want to rewrite it into a "headless" script, try to find someway to execute it within X ( X11 forwarding or something ).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What about

```
ssh me@server -i my_key "nohup python script.py >/dev/null 2>&1"
```

You can use redirection to some remote logfile instead of /dev/null of course.
? :)

EDIT: GUI applications on X usually use $DISPLAY variable to know where they should be displayed. Moreover, X11 display servers use authorization to permit or disallow applications connecting to its display. Commands

```
export DISPLAY=:0 && xhost +
```

may be helpful for you.

Comment: this seems to be going the right way, but I need to redirect it to something like /dev/tty7 (my display) since the script has a GUI output

Comment: What do you mean by "GUI output"? If it's GUI application, you need to forward X11 connections, and that's different matter, you need to run X server locally ( or it's substitute like XQuartz or sth), or access remote desktop on remote side.

Comment: no, no I dont want to forward it... Its a GUI app. But I want it to start on that server with GUI. basically I just want the GUI to appear on server machine based on my ssh request from client

Comment: consider "xhost +" command then ( it needs to be started from X client on remote machine already authorized, or included in X11 configuration / startup ) : 
    export DISPLAY=:0 && xhost +

Comment: ok, I can use google you know :P If you dont have a particular tutorial in mind, I will go with general docs :) Thanks anyway

Comment: You know, for the last fifteen years, maybe once I needed to use some  other syntax than "export DISPLAY=:0" and "xhost +" :)

Comment: this does not work....  output from remote commands coming to the local terminal overrides any ">" redirections passed on the command line to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it possible for you to rather use [python ssh extension](http://zeth.net/post/332/) instead of calling external application?

It would:

- run as one process
- guarantee that invocation will be the same among all possible system
- lose the overhead from "execution"
- send everything trough ssh (you won't have to worry about input like `"; possibly local executed command`)

If not, go with what Piotr Wades suggested.